# Why are knitr and Sweave PDF filenames numbered?

Tags: pdf, knitr, sweave

If I write a simple Rnw document containing a figure like e.g.,

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(dev = "pdf", comment = NA, fig.path = "figure/", fig.align='center', cache=FALSE, message=FALSE, background='white')
options(replace.assign=TRUE,width=85, digits = 8)
knit_hooks$set(fig=function(before, options, envir){if (before) par(mar=c(4,4,.1,.1),cex.lab=.95,cex.axis=.9,mgp=c(2,.7,0),tcl=-.3)})
@

<<prepare-data, include=FALSE>>=
@
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

A simple plot
\begin{figure}
<< scat, echo = FALSE, fig.width = 4.5, fig.height=3>>=
plot(runif(10), runif(10), pch = 20)
@
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Why does knitr create a PDF file with the filename `figure/scat-1.pdf` instead of  `figure/scat.pdf`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason was explained in the [v1.7 release notes](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/releases/tag/v1.7). In the development version (to be v1.8), you can use `fig_chunk()` to obtain the figure filenames (see package [NEWS](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md)). Also see a related discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/knitr/Rm-MqeJxtGg/discussion).

Comment: Thank you so much Yihui! I guessed that, but was not able to find the information.